# Buscar apenas data da WEB

Tags: c#, winforms

Preciso buscar a data atua à partir da Internet, no código abaixo o retorno é a data, hora, minutos e segundos.

```
public static DateTime GetNistTime()
    {
        var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.microsoft.com");
        var response = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        string todaysDates = response.Headers["date"];
        return DateTime.ParseExact(todaysDates,
                                   "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat,
                                   DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
    }
```

Como busco apenas a data, uma vez que apenas apagando o trecho `HH:mm:ss` não dá certo?

Formato de retorno:

[image: Foto]

Comment: E se tu só converter pra datetime? Depois pode converter pro formato que quiser. Qual formato tu espera?

Comment: @Aline Editei o código

Comment: Qual é o formato que tu quer? dd/MM/yyyy??

Comment: Sim: **dd/MM/yyyy**

Comment: Jovem, teu código tá certo, cara. Mostra a parte que faz o `MessageBox.Show`

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(GetNistTime().ToString());`

Comment: MessageBox.Show(GetNistTime().ToShortDateString());

Comment: E, fala pra mim, qual é a sua intenção? Mostrar no MessageBox sem a horas?

Comment: A intenção é salvar a data atual, ex: 30/05/2017 no banco de dados

Comment: E por que não salva ela então?

Comment: Porque eu precisarei comparar datas do banco com data atual, e hora, nesse caso irá me atrapalhar nisso, obtive a resposta ali em baixo, agradeço!

Comment: @jbueno E como eu adiciono dias para salvar no banco de dados, por exemplo hoje é dia 25, adicionando 5 dias, ficaria dia 30?

Comment: `data.AddDays(5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static string GetNistTime()
    {
        var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.microsoft.com");
        var response = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        string todaysDates = response.Headers["date"];
        return DateTime.Parse(todaysDates).toString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
```

Comment: Não é possível converter em `String` uma variável `System.DateTime`

Comment: Tu vai precisar trocar o retorno do método e o lugar onde busca essa informação. Ou, continue retornando dateTime no método e faço o toString("..") aonde obtém o retorno desse método.

Comment: Coloquei da mesma forma que aqui está.

Comment: Deu o mesmo erro: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'`

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

Você pode manter seu método como está, e na hora de chama-lo, basta ignorar as horas:

```
public static DateTime GetNistTime()
    {
        var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.microsoft.com");
        var response = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        string todaysDates = response.Headers["date"];
        return DateTime.ParseExact(todaysDates,
                                   "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat,
                                   DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
    }
```

Chamando o método:

```
label1.Text = GetNistTime().ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: Dessa forma o retorno continua com a hora, porém zeradas, dessa forma: **30/05/2017 00:00:00**

Comment: Não é possível converter em `String` uma variável `System.DateTime`

Comment: Todo DateTime (como o nome diz), terá data e hora. Por isso no segundo exemplo, o tipo de retorno do método foi alterado para string, e passei a retornar somente a Data

Comment: mas recomendo que utilize da sua forma inicial, retornando as horas, em seguida na hora de chamar o método você pode colocar o .ToShortDateString(); e ignorar as horas que vieram no resultado